# Weirdest obfuscated "Hello World!"

Tags: popularity-contest, obfuscation, hello-world

**Task:**

Create an obfuscated program that prints `Hello World!` (exactly like that). Your program may not have any strings in it.

**Rules:**

- You can use any programming language you like.
- Make it as *obfuscated* as possible
- This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most upvotes wins.

---

**Note:**

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world). That one was [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and it had different rules.

Comment: Who is the first to submit BF? `:)`

Comment: @VisioN - I would consider BF not really obfuscated...

Comment: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet/hw1-11.gif is a Hello World program in Piet. More information: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html

Comment: Do you consider a single char as a string?

Comment: @ProgramFOX - no

Comment: "That one was [tag:code-golf]" [doesn't make it not a duplicate](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/777/194). The rules do seem to exclude copying the answers from the older question, but principally because they exclude all answers: there's no program which can't be obfuscated more.

Comment: I disagree that they are duplicates, on different grounds than simply "The other one was a code-golf". The code-golf one required that a specific subset of characters never be used in the source code, whether it be in a string or not. There should be no matches in any of those entries against the following regex: `/[dehlorw01]/`. Also, length was graded. In this, it just requires no usage of strings (and probably no `char[][]`, wither). Length isn't counted, but creativity is the main decisive factor, thus the [tag:popularity-contest] tag.

Comment: Alas, my 100 rep bonus (for my StackOverflow rep) apparently doesn't qualify as having earned 10+ rep on codegolf, so I can't provide my .NET version as an answer.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe Association bonus does not counts to the purpose of protected questions, but I don't know why this one was protected. Anyway, getting one upvote in some other question here and get the 10 reputation poins is not hard, and then you may post your answer to this question.

Comment: No string literals or no strings at all?

Comment: @Victor I'll confess surprise that the association bonus wouldn't count towards protected questions; however, as you say, getting one upvote elsewhere isn't that hard.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe Yeah, you are not the first one here to get surprised by that SE rule.

Comment: Why did my edit get rejected? (I know it wasn't helpful, but I've voted to reopen, so don't just say "it introduced tags that are not helpful".)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Python 2

I happened to be playing with this yesterday, so:

```python
(lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________: getattr(__import__(True.__class__.__name__[_] + [].__class__.__name__[__]), ().__class__.__eq__.__class__.__name__[:__] + ().__iter__().__class__.__name__[_____:________])(_, (lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))(lambda _, __, ___: chr(___ % __) + _(_, __, ___ // __) if ___ else (lambda: _).func_code.co_lnotab, _ << ________, (((_____ << ____) + _) << ((___ << _____) - ___)) + (((((___ << __) - _) << ___) + _) << ((_____ << ____) + (_ << _))) + (((_______ << __) - _) << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << ___) + (_ << _))) + (((_______ << ___) + _) << ((_ << ______) + _)) + (((_______ << ____) - _) << ((_______ << ___))) + (((_ << ____) - _) << ((((___ << __) + _) << __) - _)) - (_______ << ((((___ << __) - _) << __) + _)) + (_______ << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << __))) - ((((((_ << ___) + _)) << __) + _) << ((((___ << __) + _) << _))) + (((_______ << __) - _) << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << _))) + (((___ << ___) + _) << ((_____ << _))) + (_____ << ______) + (_ << ___))))(*(lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))((lambda _, __, ___: [__(___[(lambda: _).func_code.co_nlocals])] + _(_, __, ___[(lambda _: _).func_code.co_nlocals:]) if ___ else []), lambda _: _.func_code.co_argcount, (lambda _: _, lambda _, __: _, lambda _, __, ___: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________: _)))
```

Here is a more readable version: http://codepad.org/UzSmoxF2

Notes:

- One line, single expression (i.e. no print statement).
- No strings, no ints; only functions, attribute access, lists, tuples, basic math, one `True`, and one star-args.
- Minimal builtin usage (`__import__`, `getattr`, and `chr` once each).
- The payload can be changed easily. [Here](http://codepad.org/oVuFVcB5) is the program I wrote to generate it.

Edit: I wrote a fairly substantial explanation of how this works [on my blog](http://earwig.github.io/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html).

Comment: Nice.  Highly readable.

Comment: "more readable version"

Comment: Congrats on 100!

Answer (score 64):

## JavaScript

```
([]+/H/)[1&11>>1]+(+[[]+(1-~1<<1)+(~1+1e1)+(1%11)+(1|1>>1|1)+(~1+1e1)+(.1^!1)])[[([]+!![
11])[11^11]+[[{}]+{}][1/1.1&1][1]]+([[]+111/!1][+!1][([{}]+{})[1e1>>1]+[[],[]+{}][1&11>>
1][1|[]]+([]+[][111])[1&1]+[{},1e1,!1+{}][~~(1.1+1.1)][1^1<<1]+(11/!{}+{})[1-~1<<1]+[!!{
}+[]][+(11>11)][[]+1]+(/^/[1.11]+/&/)[.1^!1]+[{},[{}]+{},1][1&11>>1][1+1e1+1]+([]+!!{})[
.1^!1]+([]+{}+[])[[]+1]+[!!{}+{}][!11+!111][[]+1]]+[])[(!/~/+{})[1|1<<1]+[/=/,[]+[][1]][
1&11>>1][1&1>>1]+([]+{})[~~(1.1+1.1)]+[1,!1+{}][1%11][1^1<<1]+(111/[]+/1/)[~1+1e1+~1]+[!
!/-/+[]][+(11>11)][1]]((1<<1^11)+((+(1<1))==([]+/-/[(!![11]+[])[+!1]+(!!/-/+{})[1-~1]+([
]+!/~/)[1-~1]+(!!/-/+{})[!111+!111]])[11%11]),-~11>>1)](~1-~1e1<<1<<1)+([]+{111:1111}+[]
)[11111.1%11.1*111e11|!11]+({}+/W/)[1+~1e1-(~11*1.1<<1)]+(+[[]+(1|1>>1)+(1|1>>1|1)+(11-1
>>1)+(1e1>>1|1)+(1e1>>1)+(1>>11)+(11>>>1)])[[(!!{}+[])[11>>>11]+[[]+{}][.1^!1][111%11]]+
([11/[]+[]][111%111][([{}]+[{}])[1e1>>1]+[[],[{}]+[{}]][1|1>>1|1][1|[]]+([][11]+[])[[]+1
]+[{},1e1,![1]+/~/][1<<!1<<1][1<<1^1]+(1/!1+{})[11+1>>1]+[!!/-/+{}][+(111>111)][111%11]+
([][11]+/&/)[1&1>>1]+[{},[]+{}+[],1][[]+1][11-~1+11>>1]+([]+!!/-/)[11>>11]+([]+{})[1|1>>
1|1]+[[]+!!{}][1>>>1][1&11]]+[])[(!{}+[])[1^1<<1]+[/=/,[]+[][1]][1<<1>>1][!111+!111]+([]
+{}+[])[1<<1^1>>1]+[1,![11]+[]][1|1>>1][1|1<<1|1]+(11/[]+/1/)[-~11>>1]+[!![111]+{}][+[]]
[1|1>>1]]((1e1-1)+((1&1>>1)==([]+/-/[(!!{}+{})[+(1>1)]+(!!/-/+{})[1|1<<1]+(!1+{})[1|1<<1
|1]+(!!/-/+{})[11.11>>11.11]])[1&1>>1]),1-~1<<1)](~1-~1e1<<1<<1)+(/^!/+[])[1+!![11%111]]
```

> Description of how it works can be found in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036784/1249581) on StackOverflow.

<sub>Simply run this in the browser console (e.g. in Firebug or in Chrome Dev Tools).</sub>

Answer (score 50):

### PHP

```php
<?=${[${[${[${[${[${[${[${[${${![]}.=[]}.=${![]}{!![]}]}.=${!![${[${[
${[${[${[${[${[]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}{![]+![]+![]}]}.=${[${[$
{[${[${[]}++]}++]}++]}++]}{![]}]}.=${[${[${[${[${[${[${[${[]}++]}++]}
++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}{![]+![]}.${[]}{![]+![]}]}.=${![]}^${!![${[${[${[
]}++]}++]}++]}{![]+![]+![]}]}.=${[]}{!![]}]}.=${[${[${[${[${[${[${[${
[${[${[${[${[${[${[${[${[]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++]}++
]}++]}++]}++]}++]}{![]+![]+![]+![]}.${[]}{![]+![]+![]+![]}]}.=${[${[$
{[${[]}++]}++]}++]}{![]+![]}.${![]}{![]+![]+![]}]}.=${[${![]}=${![]}{
!![]}]}{!![${!![${!![${![]}++]}++]}++]}^${!![${[${[${[]}++]}++]}++]};
```

I've translated this into a single statement, which I think makes it considerably harder to decipher. This version uses only 13 unique characters.

---

**Original version**

```php
<?${[]}.=[];${![]}.=${[]}{!![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${
![]};++${![]};${![]}.=${[]}{![]+![]+![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};${![
]}.=${![]}{![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};${
![]}.=${![]}{![]+![]}.${![]}{![]+![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};${![]}.=${[]}^${
[]}{![]+![]+![]};${![]}.=${![]}{!![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]
};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]
};++${![]};${![]}.=${![]}{![]+![]+![]+![]}.${![]}{![]+![]+![]+![]};++${![]};++${!
[]};++${![]};${![]}.=${![]}{![]+![]}.${[]}{![]+![]+![]};++${![]};++${![]};++${![]
};${[]}=${[]}{!![]};++${[]};++${[]};++${[]};${![]}.=${[]}^${![]}{![]}?><?=${![]};
```

14 unique characters. I could make a script to generate these and dub it "PHPFuck", but I don't think it would be very useful.

---

**How it works**

> When an array - including the empty array - is cast to string, the result is always the amazingly helpful string "Array". I'm not sure who thought that was a good idea. PHP supports the increment operator (but not decrement) for strings, for example "++A" → "B". The original string contains both "A" and "a", so all latin characters can be produced, brainfuck style. Space is produced with "A" ^ "a", and exclamation with "D" ^ "e".

Comment: I am very curious on how to go about creating a script to generate this type of obfuscation, if you have 5 minutes to discuss it, I would greatly appreciate it =] I will be in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13342/weirdest-obfuscations

Comment: I just took a look at the jsfuck source, interesting... I was expecting something a little more dynamic than a char map =] ... I will be chilling in that room if anyone wants to join =]

Comment: This is much better than the Javascript answer, which has `/H/` and `/W/` in it.

Answer (score 50):

## C

A multiplicative salutation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  long long P = 1,
            E = 2,
            T = 5,
            A = 61,
            L = 251,
            N = 3659,
            R = 271173410,
            G = 1479296389,
            x[] = { G * R * E * E * T , P * L * A * N * E * T };
  puts((char*)x);
}
```

Comment: You cannot have STRINGS !

Comment: I don't think he used string.  He is just type-casting it.

Comment: This is clever - and doesn't even involve undefined behavior, despite appearances (better you should use 'unsigned long long') - but only works on little-endian systems.

Answer (score 39):

### PHP

Here's a simple PHP script that outputs `Hello World!`:

```php
<?php
function SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh($_ = 0) {(
    $___=__FUNCTION__
    )&&
    !$_ and list($_,$__) = array_values(array_filter($___(42), $___)) and
    !$_($__($___)) and
    $___($___); return
    $_
    &42
    ?current(get_defined_functions()):(
    !((
    $_=md5($_))-42*2)or
    !(md5($_ = md5($_))-42/2
    *3)
);};

SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh();
```

[Click here for the demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b555319e9696e8d4e835f9bb18a8505509f4f5c)

Comment: I still have no idea why that prints anything.

Comment: @primo The function name is the key `;)`

Comment: Base64 decoding?

Comment: That too, but it's a little bit more.

Comment: @Razvan Have you tried all built in functions the check if only two hashed start with 84 and 63? That's brilliant!

Comment: Yes, that's how it actually works. I was interested in `printf` and `base64_decode` so the `md5()` comparison was the most simple (non obvious) check I could come with.

Comment: this is freaky stuff, love it

Answer (score 34):

### Whitespace

[Wikipedia: Whitespace (programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language))
[Online Interpreter to Test Answer](http://whitespace.kauaveel.ee/)

The program pushes the ASCII character codes through the following steps (taken from the interpreter debug sidebar):

```
push 72
printc
push 101
printc
push 108
printc
push 108
printc
push 111
printc
push 32
printc
push 87
printc
push 111
printc
push 114
printc
push 108
printc
push 100
printc
push 33
printc
end
```

Comment: For extra points, combine this with a non-whitespace one as well.

Answer (score 33):

## Bash (under Linux)

I hope your shell scripts don't look like this:

```
:; ______=$? __=${#______} ____=$[__+__] ________=$[__+____] _____=$[____+____]
     __________=$[____+_____] _________=$[__+__________] ______________=(
            /????/$$/????) ____________=${______________[$______]} 
   _____________=${____________##*/} _______________=(${____________//\// })
          ________________=${_______________: -$__:$__}$_____________
           ___________________=${________________:$______:$________}
   ___________=${_____________:$______:$__} _________________=${___________^}
     . <($___________________<<<__________________=\({$_________________..\
${___________}}\))&&_______=(${__________________[@]:$______:$____$__________})
  ___=(${_______[@],,})&&${___[$_____]}${___[$____]}${___[$_________]}${___[
$__$_____]} -${___[$_____]} ${_______[ $_________]}${___[${_____}]}${___[$__$__
]}${___[$__$__]}${___[$__$_____]} ${_______[$____$____]}${___[$__$_____]}${___[
$__$_________]}${___[ $__$__]}${___[$________]}\\$______$[$_____#$____$____$__]
```

- Not a single alphanumeric character - given this restriction, it hardly seems worth doing further obfuscation
- No strings (no quotes, anyway)
- There is a dependency on Linux - specifically that the `attr` file is the first file in `/proc/$PID` with a 4-character filename

See if you can spot the hidden `eval`.

Comment: There seem to be some limitation on SO rendering: I said that last line could begin by `${__[${____}]}${__[${__________}]}${__[${_______}]}${__[${___}${____}]} -${__[${____}]} ` (`echo -e`) and replace `!`  by `\\${_________}${____}${___}`

Comment: or worst: `\\${_________}$[${______}${____}#${_____[${___________}+${__________}]}]` make an exclamation point too;-)

Comment: This is _pretty_.  But there are a couple of problems: (1) it isn't quite portable, I can't get it to run _as is_ on BSD.  (2) the script assumes that `_________` would be set to `0` (what would happen if the script were `source`d instead after an error?).

Comment: @devnull 2) is easy to fix - just run the `:` command to clear any previous error conditions reported in `$?`.

Comment: @devnull as for 1), I never made any claims of portability ;-).  What is the problem in BSD - dependence on `/proc/$PID/attr` or something else?  I'd love to figure out how to do this in a portable manner, but I haven't figured out how to get past the `/proc/$PID/attr` dependency yet.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I know that.  Just wanted to point out the obvious issue.  That said, it's very pretty.  Nice!

Comment: Any prizes for spotting `eval`?  Brace expansion, err...

Comment: @devnull Sorry, no prizes, other than a smug sense of self satisfaction ;-)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Could I edit your answer to add a justified version with no more than 79 columns and 15 lines, more suitable for cut'n paste... (I dislike long line with 285 characters)??

Comment: @F.Hauri please go ahead!  I'm open to any edits on this one, so long as no alphanumeric characters or quotes are introduced (and the program remains correct).

Comment: @F.Hauri How is it possible that these comments go for so long before line-wrapping? (screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YzkhP.png)

Comment: @Quincunx It's the reason because I've edited original post... Unfortunely, comments stay hard to read (selection and copy seem correct)... Maybe the best is simply to drop them?!

Answer (score 29):

### GolfScript

```
[' '(..4/++][' '(3*)))))][6`(2*.]['1'..++~][8 2?2/][' '(4/.(`\`\+~]['1'.+~2?10-][13(1)?8((0)))))*-][6`(1)*]['('(4/2?][' '()]+++++++++++
```

It was quite challenging to create and debug this. It doesn't contain strings, only chars.

It outputs:

> Hello World!

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=WycgJyguLjQvKytdWycgJygzKikpKSkpXVs2YCgyKi5dWycxJy4uKyt%2BXVs4IDI%2FMi9dWycgJyg0Ly4oYFxgXCt%2BXVsnMScuK34yPzEwLV1bMTMoMSk%2FOCgoMCkpKSkpKi1dWzZgKDEpKl1bJygnKDQvMj9dWycgJygpXSsrKysrKysrKysr)

#### Explanation

How this works:

1. `[' '(..4/++]`

   1. `' '(` converts the space to its ASCII code: `32`.
   2. `..` duplicates `32` twice. Now you have three times `32`.
   3. `4/` divides the top `32` by 4. Now you have twice `32` and once `8`.
   4. `++` adds up the `32`, `32` and `8`. You get `72`, which is the ASCII code for `H`.
2. `[' '(3*)))))]`

   1. `' '(` converts the space to `32`.
   2. `3*` multiplies the `32` with `3`: `96`
   3. `)))))` increases `96` with 5, you get `101`, which is the ASCII code for `e`.
3. `` [6`(2*.] ``

   1. `` 6`( `` gives the ASCII code of the char `6`: `54`
   2. `2*` multiplies it with 2, you get `108`, which is the ASCII code for `l`.
   3. `.` duplicates the `l`
4. `['1'..++~]`

   1. `'1'..` puts the char `1` on the stack and duplicates it twice.
   2. `++` concatenates the three chars and returns the string `111`
   3. `~` converts it to the integer `111`, which is the ASCII code for `o`
5. `[8 2?2/]`

   1. `8 2?` calculates 8<sup>2</sup>, you get `64`
   2. `2/` divides it by 2, you get `32`, which is the ASCII code for a space.
6. `` [' '(4/.(`\`\+~] ``

   1. `' '(` converts the space to `32`.
   2. `4/.` divides it by 4, you get `8`. The `.` duplicates it.
   3. `` (` `` decrements the second `8` and converts it to a string.
   4. `\` swaps the top two elements. The `8` becomes the top element.
   5. `` ` `` converts the `8` to a string.
   6. `\` swaps the top two elements. The `7` becomes the top element.
   7. `+` concatenates the two strings. You get `87` (as a string).
   8. `~` converts the string `87` to the integer `87`, which is the ASCII code for `W`.
7. `['1'.+~2?10-]`

   1. `'1'.` puts the char `1` on the stack and duplicates it.
   2. `+~` concatenates the two chars to the string `11` and converts it to an integer.
   3. `2?` calculates 11<sup>2</sup>, you get `121`.
   4. `10-` decreases `121` with 10, you get the ASCII code for `o`: `111`.
8. `[13(1)?8((0)))))*-]`

   1. `13(` puts `12` on the stack.
   2. `1)` puts `2` on the stack.
   3. `?` calculates 12<sup>2</sup>, you get `144`.
   4. `8((` puts `6` on the stack.
   5. `0)))))` puts `5` on the stack.
   6. `*` multiplies `6` and `5`, you get `30`.
   7. `-` substracts `144` with `30`, you get `114`, which is the ASCII code for `r`
9. `` [6`(1)*] ``

   1. `` 6`( `` converts `6` to a char and takes its ASCII code: `54`
   2. `1)*` multiplies `54` with `2`, you get `108`, the ASCII code of `l`
10. `['('(4/2?]`

    1. `'('(` converts `(` to its ASCII code, `40`.
    2. `4/` divides `40` by `4`, you get `10`.
    3. `2?` calculates 10<sup>2</sup>, you get `100`, which is the ASCII code for `d`
11. `[' '()]`

    1. `' '(` converts the space to its ASCII code: `32`
    2. `)` increments the `32`, you get `33`, which is the ASCII code for `!`
12. `+++++++++++` concatenates all ASCII codes to one string.

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation. This is unusual for golfscript answers for some reason.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm pretty sure there's a good reason

Comment: This is the first time that I see a long GolfScript answer for a normally trivially solved problem.

Answer (score 20):

### Brainf***

Not sure if this really counts as obfuscated, but it never uses more than four plus or minus symbols in a row. So there's that.

```
>>+++[<+++>-]<+[>+++>>+++[<+++>-]<+[<]>-]<+++[>+++<-]>+[>++++<-]>++.>+.>+++
[<++>-]<+..+++.<<<+++[>+++<-]>+[>----<-]>.>[>+>+<<-]++++[>++<-]>.>.+++.>++[
<--->-]<.>++[<---->-]<.<<<+.
```

Comment: +1 for saying anything Brainfuck might not count as obfuscated.

Comment: meanwhile, back in 1992... "Every program can be obfuscated! And when every program's obfuscated..." <Urban Müller chuckles evilly> "*no program* will be..."

Answer (score 19):

## Mathematica

Simple Algebra I math.

```
a=+x+8x^2+8(x^3+x^9);
b=11(x^4+x^7)-68x^5-13x^6;
c=-28+14x^8-67x^11;
w=ToExpression[Names[__][[1571]]];  
v=ToExpression[Names[__][[604]]]; 
y=Solve[a+b+c,{x},Reals];  
w[v[y[[1]],x]+100]
```

> Hello World!

Comment: `FromCharacterCode` breaks all intrigue...

Comment: VisionN, `FromCharacterCode` is now obfuscated. So is `CoefficientList`.

Answer (score 17):

### **C**

```c
#define u unsigned char
#define v while(*x)
#define z(x) putchar(*x);
#define y(x) ++*x;
#define p(x) ++x;
#define e(x) --*x;
#define d(x) --x;
#define w(x) x x
main(){u *x=calloc(12,1);u *l=x;w(w(w(y(x))))w(y(x))v{p(x)w(w(y(x)))w(y(x))y(x)p
(x)w(w(w(y(x))))w(y(x))p(x)w(y(x))y(x)p(x)w(w(w(y(x))))y(x)w(w(d(x)))e(x)}p(x)w(
y(x))z(x)p(x)y(x)z(x)w(w(y(x)))w(y(x))y(x)w(z(x))w(y(x))y(x)z(x)p(x)w(y(x))z(x)p
(x)w(e(x))e(x)z(x)w(d(x))z(x)w(y(x))y(x)z(x)w(w(e(x)))w(e(x))z(x)w(w(w(e(x))))z(
x)p(x)y(x)z(x)free(l);}
```

Meta-obfuscated.  Running this through the preprocessor gives you this:

```c
main(){unsigned char *x=calloc(12,1);unsigned char *l=x;++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x;++*x; ++*x;while(*x){++x;++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x;++*x; ++*x;++*x;++x;
   ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x;++*x; ++*x;++x;++*x; ++*x;++*x;++x;++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x;++*x;--x; --x; --x; --x;--*x;}++x;++*x; ++*x;
     putchar(*x);++x;++*x;putchar(*x);++*x; ++*x; ++*x; ++*x;++*x; ++*x;++*x;putchar(*x); putchar(*x);++*x; ++*x;++*x;putchar(*x);++x;++*x; ++*x;putchar(*x);++x;
   --*x; --*x;--*x;putchar(*x);--x; --x;putchar(*x);++*x; ++*x;++*x;putchar(*x);--*x; --*x; --*x; --*x;--*x; --*x;putchar(*x);--*x; --*x; --*x; --*x; --*x; --*x; --*x; --*x;putchar(*x);
  ++x;++*x;putchar(*x);free(l);}
```

Output:

> Hello World!

**Edit:** added syntax highlighting for clarity. :-P

Comment: Nice. Never seen BF logic used in C before.

Comment: @OP Removing `u *l=x;` and `free(l);` gives me the same result.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows What is BF logic?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

Answer (score 15):

## [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)

```py
for i in 5105882569598991528047304.digits(1+sum(2**j for j in 11382954456.digits(42))):
    sys.stdout.write(chr(i))
```

Explanation:

`11382954456.digits(42)` converts 11382954456 into base 42 and gives an array of its digits, which is `[6, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2]`

So the `sum` actually gives the sum of 1+2+4+...+32+64, which is 127

Then `5105882569598991528047304.digits(...)` converts the number into base 128, which gives the list `[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]`

And these are the ASCII codes for the string to be printed.

Comment: Never heard of sage before

Comment: @TheDoctor edited to add a hyperlink to the Sage webpage.

Comment: It looks a lot like python

Comment: @TheDoctor because Sage is based on python

Answer (score 15):

### Javascript (28187 chars)

Probably not the shortest way to say hello to this world.

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

Generated with [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/)

Comment: +1 I was willing to post a JSFuck answer too, but you did it first.

Comment: Possibly you should mention that you have generated this code with [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/).

Comment: Duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17950/3103. And yes, there are shorter ways to do so.

Answer (score 12):

### C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BING(x,y) ((x)<<y)
#define BANG(x)   (1<<x)
#define BOOM      1
int main () {
  int x,y,z,w;
  int V[3] = {BING(x=227380393,BANG(BOOM)+BOOM), x+(w=BOOM+BANG(BANG(BOOM)),
              BING(47*y=17453197,BOOM)), x+y+BING(w*w*17*185527,BANG(BOOM))};
  char *p=V;
  while(*(p-BOOM)!=BOOM+BING(BOOM,w)) putchar(*p++);
  return 0;
} /* Mind the comma operator! */
```

**Outputs:**

`Hello World!`

Comment: Integer array with some bit shifts...well played. I also like the last one being right-shifted a pretty large number.

Answer (score 12):

## Malbolge

```
('&%:9]!~}|z2Vxwv-,POqponl$Hjig%eB@@>}=<M:9wv6WsU2T|nm-,jcL(I&%$#"
`CB]V?Tx<uVtT`Rpo3NlF.Jh++FdbCBA@?]!~|4XzyTT43Qsqq(Lnmkj"Fhg${z@>
```

or

```
(=<`#9]~6ZY32Vx/4Rs+0No-&Jk)"Fh}|Bcy?`=*z]Kw%oG4UUS0/@-ejc(:'8dc
```

I have no clue how this works.

<sup>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge#.22Hello_World.21.22_in_Malbolge</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the entire **point** of Malbolge was that nobody had a clue how it worked.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe Yeah, but not everyone knows that.

Comment: You beat me to this one (+1).

Comment: And yet someone, somehow, completed the 99 Bottles challenge using Malbolge: http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-malbolge-995.html

In fact, someone else did it as well: http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-malbolge-375.html

Answer (score 11):

## Java

Here it is. Can you understand how it works?

Warning: Very volatile. May break spontaneuosly in the future.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MysteryCode {
    public static void main(String[] unused) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stoned = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
        int[] magic = {104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 98, 105, 116, 46, 108, 121, 47, 49, 98, 87, 119, 51, 75, 111};
        for (int weird : magic) stoned.write(weird);
        int crazy, unknown = 0;
        java.io.InputStream wtf = new java.net.URL(stoned.toString()).openStream();
        while((crazy = wtf.read()) != -1) stoned.write(crazy);
        for (int strange : stoned.toByteArray()) {
            if (unknown == 2) {
                if (strange == 38) break;
                System.out.print((char) strange);
            } else if (17 + (unknown + 1) * 21 == strange) {
                unknown++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting you built a parser for this page. Very well done

Comment: I suppose you wouldn't mind if someone changed the title to this question? ;)

Comment: @Cruncher I think that the title of the question is perfect and see absolutely no reason for changing it ever. `;)`

Comment: If you were golfing you can actually reduce your "unknown" array to `{38, 59}` and change your maximum for u to 2 instead of 6. That may also be harder for others to read. Instead of your "unknown" being `$quot;` it would just be `&;`. (this would be less versatile, but would still work with the current title)

Comment: @Cruncher Ok, I started to do that, but this gave me opportunities for better obfuscations, so It became what it is now.

Comment: Interestingly using variable names like crazy, unknown and strange are harder to read than using x, y, z. It's easy to differentiate between x's, y's, and z's, but (psuedo-)synonyms can trip you up.

Comment: @Cruncher Really, you are right. Renamed the remaining variables to make it harder in this way.

Comment: `while((crazy = wtf.read()) != -1) stoned.write(crazy);` xD

Answer (score 10):

**Befunge**

Code that says "Hello, World!":

```
>55+7*2+,  v >4*4+v
              ,
v,+1*+55+55< +v55<>55+3*2+,v
>55+55+*8+,v 5+  +v,+7*8+55<
v,+8*+55+55< 5*  5>55+55+*56++,v
>55+55+*56++,^8  5v,++59*+55+55<
v+55,*+55+55,+<  ^<
>3*3+,@
```

Code that says "Hello World!":

```
>55+7*2+,  v >    v

v,+1*+55+55<  v55<>55+3*2+,v
>55+55+*8+,v  +  +v,+7*8+55<
v,+8*+55+55<  *  5>55+55+*56++,v
>55+55+*56++,^8  5v,++59*+55+55<
v+55,*+55+55,+<  ^<
>3*3+,@
```

Comment: Umm, on the beginning it said "Hello, World" (with a comma), and the new one said "Hello World" without a comma.

Comment: And now I have reedit it.

Comment: Oh. Revision 2 makes more sense now. I only saw Revision 1 when editing (no idea why). Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No problem... Glad it makes sense now :).

Answer (score 10):

## Befunge 98 - 7610 characters

```
'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,  '/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+'/'[\/+,@
```

Based on my answer here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15736/9498

As a bonus, this answer does not use any numbers and contains no redundant characters (that is there is no combination of characters that could be removed such that it produces the same output).

Try it out here (paste code, replace every instance of `'/'[` with `"/["`): http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html

How it works:

> `'/'[\/` is equivalent to 1, so all this does is increment to the corresponding ASCII Values, then prints.

Extra bonus: this post is so long that it takes ~1 second before stackexchange recognizes the changes in writing this post.

Comment: You're still using strings though... Even "/[" is a string.

Comment: @Misteriggy Whoops missed that requirement. Fixing...

Comment: @Misteriggy There. Now it does not use strings.

Answer (score 10):

## Brainf**k

It's obfuscated, and yet, it couldn't be simpler.

```
+   +  +++++  +      [         >++
+   +  [      >      +        +   >
+++>+  ++>+<  <      <        <   -       
]   >  +      >      +        >   -    >
>   +  >+[<]  <-]>>  .>---     .++    +

+   +   ++.   .+++   .        >>.<     -
W . <  .   +  +   +  .        -   -    -
- - -  .   -  ----   -        -   -    .
 > >   +   .  > +    +        .   <
        >>>   <  <   >>><<    <><>     >
```

Because when you look closely:

```
H   H  EEEEE  L      L         OOO
H   H  E      L      L        O   O
HHHHH  EEEEE  L      L        O   O       
H   H  E      L      L        O   O     ,
H   H  EEEEE  LLLLL  LLLLL     OOO     ,

W   W   OOO   RRRR   L        DDDD     !
W W W  O   O  R   R  L        D   D    !
W W W  O   O  RRRR   L        D   D    !
 W W   O   O  R R    L        D   D
        OOO   R  R   LLLLL    DDDD     !
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2.6+

```python
p = lambda x: ( -13214 * x**11 + 956318 * x**10 - 30516585 * x**9 + 564961485 * x**8
                - 6717043212 * x**7 + 53614486464 * x**6 - 291627605005 * x**5
                + 1074222731065 * x**4 - 2606048429424 * x**3 + 3927289106268 * x**2
                - 3265905357360 * x + 1116073728000 ) / 19958400

print bytearray(map(p, range(1, 13)))
```

No strings, just [a simple polynomial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript

**No number literals, no string literals, and only one function (not including `console.log`)!**

```
var ________________ = [] + []; var _ = +[]; _++; var _____ = _ + _;
var ___ = _____ + _____; var __ = ___ + ___; var ____ = __ + __; var ______ = ____ + ____;
var _______ = ______ + _; var ___________ = ______ + ______ + __;
var ______________ = ___________ + ____ -  _; var ____________ = _ + _____;
var ________ = _______ * ____________ + _; var _________ = ________ + _;
var _____________ = ______________ + ______ - ___ - _; var __________ = _____________ -
____________; var _______________ = __________ - ____________; console.log(________________ +
String.fromCharCode(___________, _________, _______________, _______________, __________,
______, ______________, __________, _____________, _______________, ________, _______));
```

Demonstration [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/obfuscated-code/5989035086446592).

Comment: But isn't `[]` a literal?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That might be true, but it's not a number or string literal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread what you were saying. You said `No number literals`, and I skipped the number. If you want, can use `Array()` instead. That wouldn't be a literal. And it would make it more confusing. Alternatively, you can use `+false` for the `+[]`. Or even `Array()-Array()`.

Answer (score 6):

## [This](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/two-dimensional-programming-language/6252487852687360) Programming Language

```
            'Alice'++++7/4+v
v     -9/3++'was'          <
>           'beginning'++++++++9/3+v
v      -5/2+'to'                   <
>           'get'++3/5+v
v  -&81/9+++'very'     <
>           'tired'++++6/2-v
v      +5/2+'of'           <
>           'sitting'++++++7/4+v
v      -1/2+'by'               <
>           'her'++3/6-v
v-&14/9+++++'sister'   <
>           'on'~~v
v        ~~~'the' <
>           'bank.'~~~~~s;
```

Can you guess what it does?
Perhaps you'll have to go deeper into the rabbit-hole to find out.

**DISCLAIMER:** Programming language is newer than challenge.

Comment: That is a worthy disclaimer.

Comment: The interpreter was broken by the new Khan Academy specs, I'll need to find a way to fix that; I think I can bypass the specs by embedding in in an HTML page though.

Answer (score 5):

## C

```c
int main() {
    // Some floating point numbers for testing
    float b[] = {1.1431391224375825e+27, 6.6578486920496456e+28, 7.7392930965627798e-19, 3.2512161851627752e-9};
    // Print all numbers in array b[]
    puts(b);

    return 0;
}
```

The comments are there just to mislead uninformed readers.

The constants are constructed so that its representation in the memory (for little-endian systems) is the same as the string `"Hello World!"`. Then the array (decays to pointer) is passed to `puts`, where `puts` blindly treats it as a `char*` and print everything until it hits `NUL` (which is coded in the last number).

The code compiles (with warnings) and prints the expected output with gcc 4.7.0, Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 5):

## Java

```
class M‮{public static void main(String[]a‭){System.out.print(new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','!'});}}
```

[Test here.](http://ideone.com/t1W5Vm)

I know, kind of lame to use characters instead of strings. Weird that it runs correctly. Isn't it?

Comment: Wait... what?! What's the mechanism behind this one?

Comment: There is a unicode "[RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm)" character just after the M, and the opposite (left to right) just before the `a[]`.

Answer (score 3):

C (honestly, 90% C preprocessor):

```
#if __COUNTER__ == 0
#define Y
#define X(a) a##ng a##ng
#define values(a,b,c,d) _ d c = b 5237610348992605899, -8965656808041882953, -3202399561689361469, -7073034487879198273, -7020069900579512688, -33906882022564967 a
#define W(a) (){
#define _Q(a,b,c,d,e) e##a##d##e##c 0; b
#define Q(a,b,c,d) _Q(a,b,c,d,r)
#define K (char
main W(lo) X(lo) values(},{,],[);
#endif
#ifndef T
#undef W
#define W _-
#define Z 35
#define T Y+0
#endif
putchar((*_=(X(lo))(K*)(_+((*W 1)&-(*W 0)|!T))+__COUNTER__),~*K*)(*W 1)));
#if __COUNTER__ <= Z
#include "main.c"
#else
Q(e,},n,tu)
#endif
```

Only with gcc or another compiler that supports the `__COUNTER__` macro.

Answer (score 3):

## C++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char    g=16777288,
            r=16777317,
            e=16777324,
            t=16777327,
           sp=16777248,
            w=16777303,
            o=16777327,
            R=16777330,
            l=16777324,
            d=16777316,
           ex=16777249;
    std::cout
            <<g
            <<r
            <<e
            <<e
            <<t
                <<sp//space
                    <<w
                    <<o
                    <<R
                    <<l
                    <<d
                        <<ex;//exclamatory
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to upvote you if you got rid of the constants o and l. You don't need them, use r and t instead.

Comment: @steveverrill that won't make the presentation I want...'greet world' still i'll try

Answer (score 3):

(I know it's not really *weird*.)

### dc

```
dc<<<"8 9*P101P108P108P111P4 8*P81 6+P111P114P108P100P33P"
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: I get "Hello World!$" where $ is my prompt.  Add 10P at the end to get a newline.

Comment: alternatively `dc<<<5735816763073005734600101863690P`

Answer (score 3):

## C#

No string or character literals, although string functions **are** used. Obfuscation via rot13.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CodeGolf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Jevgrf "Uryyb Jbeyq!" gb gur pbafbyr.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Guvf cebtenz vf n cebcbfrq fbyhgvba gb dhrfgvba 
    /// ahzore 22533 ng pbqrtbys.fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz:</para>
    /// <para>Perngr na boshfpngrq cebtenz gung cevagf Uryyb 
    /// Jbeyq! (rknpgyl yvxr gung). Lbhe cebtenz znl abg unir 
    /// nal fgevatf va vg.</para>
    /// <para>Fnyhgba Zbaqb vf Rfcrenagb sbe Uryyb Jbeyq.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    class FnyhgbaZbaqb
    {
        class Genafyngbe
        {
            int bssfrg = 0;
            public char Genafyngr(string vachg)
            {
                return vachg.Length < 6
                    ? (char)(37 + (bssfrg -= bssfrg) - vachg.Length)
                    : vachg.ToCharArray()[bssfrg++];
            }
        }
        enum UryybJbeyq
        {
            Hoover,
            Denver,
            WillowPrimus,
            WillowSecundus,
            WillowTertius,
            Fnord,
            Wintergreen,
            Copacetic,
            Pursuing,
            Follicle,
            Remedies,
            Bang
        }
        void Terrg(TextWriter tw)
        {
            Genafyngbe gf = new Genafyngbe();
            foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetNames(typeof(UryybJbeyq)))
            {
                tw.Write(gf.Genafyngr(enumVal));
            }
            tw.WriteLine();
            tw.Flush();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FnyhgbaZbaqb urryb = new FnyhgbaZbaqb();
            urryb.Terrg(Console.Out);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to the 33th bit of a 4byte-integer does that work...

Comment: @masterX244 quite nicely, thank you :-)

Comment: @masterX244 A hint: it's looping through the names of the `UryybJbeyq` enum and either incrementing the index of which letter to grab from the name or resetting the index, based on how long the name is.

Comment: nice :) now i seee

Answer (score 3):

## C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define o stdout
#define p fputs
int main(_){int*I=&_,_I=2113,l1=3271;_=14557;_I*=503;_<<=3;_*='=';_I<<=0==0;_I=7*'Y'*853<<2;
p(I,o);I=&_I;p(I,o);I=&_;

    _+= l1*11*11;

_I += 0xF5<<8;p(I,o);I=&_I;p(I,o);}
```

No strings, no arrays, no characters, very few obvious "data-storing large constants".

Answer (score 3):

## ><> [(Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

I made a little maze for the instruction pointer in ><>

```
>v ^3::+7:\v-<  /8<
v>6c*aa*1+/>!^:!/3 \
>l?\;| !:6!+-!3:!<^>,r
\ o/+:&84*:3*9-&:^
```

[Online ><> interpreter here](http://fishlanguage.com/)

Answer (score 2):

#### bash

```
#!/bin/bash

varval () { 
    local _i _func='{ local _lt=({0..9} {a..z} {A..Z} @ _) _var _out;
                    printf -v _var %022o $1 ;_out="';
    for ((_i=0; _i<22; _i+=2)) ;do
        printf -v _func '%s${_lt[8#${_var:%d:2}]}' "$_func" $_i;
    done;
    _func+='";printf ${2:+-v} $2 %s ${_out##*(0)}; }';
    eval "${FUNCNAME}()" $_func;
    $FUNCNAME $@
}
varval ${?}7230332515 x
varval ${!}725177688  y
printf -v z %b \\0$[64#F]
echo $y $x$z
```

There is no strings, except function builder! This print exactly:

```
Hello World!
```

And I will let you understand how ;-)

Comment: I see quite a few strings in that, although I'm not sure how you'd avoid that in bash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a great deal is in the abuse of `printf`'s parameter parsing.

Comment: @fluffy strings are suppressed. The only string left is function builder... This could be replaced by evaled function but become less funny.

Comment: @impinball under [tag:bash], `printf` is a *builtin*. This open ways to very powerfull behaviours!

Comment: @F.Hauri I know (I've used it before).

Comment: @fluffy Avoiding strings in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22590/11259) - sort of.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yep, saw that one. Impressive. :) I'm not sure it's really possible to actually avoid strings in a language that makes no real distinction between strings and anything else though. I mean, `echo Hello, World\!` has no string characters in it...

Comment: @fluffy agreed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2

```
print reduce(lambda _,__:_+chr(__+32+((__+30)>>5)*34),map(lambda _:0x24f8e8f7141b0/22**_%22,xrange(12)),str()).title()
```

Meh.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell

Paste it as it is (4 separate lines) and run in PowerShell, you'll see "Hello World!" as output.

I leave it on you to de-obfuscate it.

```
$arr = @()
$arr += 104;$arr += 116;$arr += 116;$arr += 112;;$arr += 58;$arr += 47;$arr += 47;$arr += 116;$arr += 105;$arr += 110;$arr += 121;$arr += 117;$arr += 114;$arr += 108;$arr += 46;$arr += 99;$arr += 111;$arr += 109;$arr += 47;$arr += 50;$arr += 52;$arr += 56;$arr += 99;$arr += 57
$u = [char[]]$arr -join [string]$null
(iwr $u).ParsedHtml.title.substring(0, 12)
```

Outputs

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java (3359 chars)

Gotta love that compiler! :)

```
public class a{
  public static void main(String[]String){
    /*\u0077\u006F\u0077\u0020\u0075\u006E\u0069\u0063\u006F\u0064\u0065\u0020\u0069\u0073\u0020\u0066\u0075\u006E\u002A\u002F
      \u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u0020\u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u003D\u0033\u0032\u003B
      \u0061\u0028\u0061\u0028\u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u002E\u0075\u0074\u0069\u006C
      \u002E\u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u0028\u0039\u0031\u0036\u0038\u0037\u0030\u0035\u0029\u0029\u0029\u003B
      \u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D\u002E\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074
      \u0028\u0028\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0029\u0028\u002B\u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u0029\u0029\u003B
      \u0061\u0028\u0061\u0028\u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u002E\u0075\u0074\u0069\u006C\u002E
      \u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u0028\u0032\u0039\u0032\u0030\u0034\u0032\u0035\u0029\u0029\u0029\u003B
      \u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D\u002E\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u006C\u006E
      \u0028\u0028\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0029\u0028\u0031\u002B\u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u0029\u0029\u003B
      \u007D\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006F\u0069\u0064\u0020\u0061\u0028\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072
      \u005B\u005D\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u0029\u007B\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u005B\u0030\u005D\u003D
      \u0043\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0061\u0063\u0074\u0065\u0072\u002E\u0074\u006F\u0055\u0070\u0070\u0065\u0072\u0043\u0061\u0073\u0065
      \u0028\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u005B\u0030\u005D\u0029\u003B\u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D
      \u002E\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u0029\u003B\u007D\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063
      \u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u002E\u0069\u006F\u002E\u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D
      \u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D\u003D\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006D\u002E\u006F\u0075\u0074\u003B
      \u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u005B\u005D\u0061\u0028\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u002E\u0075\u0074\u0069\u006C
      \u002E\u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u0020\u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u0029\u007B\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0020
      \u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u005B\u005D\u002C\u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u003B\u0066\u006F\u0072
      \u0028\u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u003D\u0030\u002C\u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u003D\u006E\u0065\u0077
      \u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u005B\u0035\u005D\u003B\u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u003C\u0035\u003B\u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D
      \u005B\u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u002D\u0031\u005D\u003D\u0028\u0063\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0029\u0028
      \u0049\u006E\u0074\u0065\u0067\u0065\u0072\u002E\u006E\u0065\u0078\u0074\u0049\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0032\u0037\u0029\u002B\u0039\u0037\u0029\u0029
      \u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u002B\u002B\u003B\u0072\u0065\u0074\u0075\u0072\u006E\u0020\u0052\u0061\u006E\u0064\u006F\u006D\u003B\u002F\u002A*/
  }
}
```

If you want to bother reversing it, the native2ascii JDK tool can fix it in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct s
{
int64_t i[9];
}S;
#define N 11
int main()
{
    int s=sizeof(S),i=s,j=N;
    int x[N]={i,i+=29,i+=7,i,i+=3,2*N+10,s+=15,i,i+=3,i-=6,i-=8};
    while(j--)
    {
        putchar(x[N-1-j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip)

Seems an effective method of obfuscation.

Code:

```
m[acr+`m)`a]`{{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwO`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwO`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwO`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwO`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwW`{wWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwWwO``
```

Comment: Well, weird word warpers write wild wondrous writings which win, while words work wishful wisecrackers who will wrench W wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

The **[Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_Stacking_Pseudo-Assembly_Language)**

```
20000F
400100
20000F
400100
200003
400100
210100
210100
410100
400000
200064
400000
20006C
400000
200072
400000
20006F
400000
200057
400000
200020
400000
20002C
400000
410000
20006F
400000
20006C
400000
420000
400000
200065
400000
200048
400000
140000
```

(I've been told to tell you that this is not, technically, an entry in the challenge)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You're more than welcome to show off your new challenge on some old answers. However, policy is that only languages older than a challenge are allowed to win that challenge (because otherwise people will just create languages which can solve the challenge with a built in). [Consensus is](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4871/8478) that you may still answer, but should include a disclaimer that this answer is not competitive (not eligible for being accepted) if you are answering a challenge older than your language.

Comment: The same goes for some other answers - I suggest you (@SuperJedi224) go through the other [answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39022/superjedi224?tab=answers) you posted and include a little disclaimer ; ) Personally (feel free to disagree), I think you're better off showing off your language to **new** challenges, so we can see the full potential of your language instead of only the challenges that seem to fit your language well. Furthermore, as far as your language goes, I'm not sure this is obfuscated, as this seems to be the 'normal' way of doing Hello World in your language.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Does this mean we can still vote on it?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Of course you can.

Answer (score 2):

## C

```
??=include <stdio.h>
??=define P_ putchar;
??=define _defined 0
#define if(c) Cb(le,whi) (c)
??=define G_ 0x48;
??=define r return
#define SS 0
??=define E S
??=define NL
??=define _defjned v
#define while(c) Cb(f,i) (c)
??=define C(d,...) d##__VA_ARGS__
%:define Cb(a,...) __VA_ARGS__##a
??=define v C(S,S)
%:define m$ _defined
int True = _defjned;
#define def_i( m ) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) ??< while(argc == m$ + !True)??< return m$; ??> if(True) { while(True){} } else { return 1; } ??>
??=ifndef __cplusplus
??=undef _defined
??=define _void int
??=define i _void
??=define m$ void
%:define _defined 1
??=undef _defined
??=undef SS
??=define SS 1
??=define c_ char
??=define Z$ ;
??=define Z$$ )
??=define _T typedef
??=define u unsigned
??=define jakjf c_
??=define jaofhouwa u jakjf
_T jaofhouwa z_;i a;c_ c;i (*p)(i c);
??=undef i
??=undef def_i
??=ifndef i
??=define i int
??=define _defined i
??=endif
%:ifdef i
??=define j void
??=define x2 0x2
%:define S_ 4
??=define B 0xB
??=else
??=undef _defined
??=endif
%:define def_i(m) m main () ??< _b() Z$ ??>
??=define M(z,k_) z * k_
i _d(),_c(),_b(),_nP_(z_ b),_a(z_ b);i _a(z_ b)??<r (c ? (p(b)) : _nP_(b) Z$$ Z$ ??>i _nP_(z_ b)??<p = &P_ c = ~(!_defjned && ~0xFF) Z$ r _a(b);??>i _b()??<a = G_ Z$ _c()Z$ ??>i _c()??<_a(_a((_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(_a(a)*2-0x2B)+7))+3)&0+0x20)+0x57)-8)+3)-6)-8)&0)+33)-23);??>i _d()??<??>def_i( m$ )
??=ifdef _defined
??=undef _defined
??=endif
%:else
def_i( m$ );
??=endif
```

Compiles on `gcc` with `-trigraphs`. Note: **DO NOT COMPILE THIS WITH `g++` or `clang++` or any C++ compiler. It will output nothing.**

Comment: This is so awful. And wonderful. +1

Answer (score 2):

## Cardinal

I just used + - * , % \ / and @

I know, I could have done a better job, but this should suffice for the moment.

```
%+++++++++++++++\
 /+++++++++++++\+
 +/++++++~****\++
 ++/*********\*++
 ++*/++++,**\**+~
 ++,+/++,**\*+*+*
 +++++/+++\+*+*,*
 +++*+*/+\++*+++*
 +++*+*+@/*+*+,+*
 ++,*+*\+*/+*+*+,
 +++*+\++++/*+*+~
 +++*\++++++/+++-
 ++*\******,+/++-
 ++\,+++++++++/+-
 ~\+++++~,+++,,/-
 \--------------/
```

Maybe this one looks a tiny little bit less obvious:

```
%+++++++++++++++\
 /+++++++++++++O+
 +O++++++~****v++
 ++>*********O*++
 ++*/++++,**\**+~
 ++,+O++,**v*+*+*
 +++++/+++O+*+*,*
 +++*+*>+\++*+++*
 +++*+*+@O*+*+,+*
 ++,*+*^+*<+*+*+,
 +++*+\++++O*+*+~
 +++*^++++++/+++-
 ++*\******,+<++-
 ++O,+++++++++O+-
 ~\+++++~,+++,,/-
 ^--------------O
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ziim](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ziim)

This language would be pointless, if only it didn’t have so many arrows pointing at each other.

```
    ↘↓                        
        ↘                     
↘          ←              ↙   
          ⤢↘           ↘← ↑   
 ↘←     ↑⤡↙ → ↙         ↓↙↙   
      ↙  → ↗           ↙      
 ↘ ←  ↙↙↘     ↙↘ ↙     ↑   ↘← 
↘     ↑↕ ←     ↓↓↑      ↙   ← 
  ↘   ←  ↙ ↕← ↗            ↔↙ 
     ↗↓ ↑↑  →↖  ↙←  ↓   ↘     
 →    ↘ ↘   ↓↘← ↗     ↙↙      
   ↙    ↖ ↘  ←↓↙←     ↑  ↑↑   
↑ →         ↘  →          ↙   
     ↘        ↙      ←↙       
  ↘  ↕     ↔       ↙↙     ←  ↙
                  ⤡           
    ↑ ↘  ←↓↓↓ ↓↓↓   ↙↘        
        ↘→  ↘ ↙  ←    ↑       
   ↓  ↘  → ↘   ↙ ←            
         →↘ ↓ ↓ ↙←   ↕←       
       ↗   →↘ ↙←              
         →↗  ↓  ↖←   ↖ ↕ ↔  ↙ 
    ↗↔ ↖  ↑↓   ↙↑ ↖←       ↑↘ 
    ↙       ↓ →↗→↖↑ ↑        ↑
           ↗↖  ↑→ ↙↓ ↙        
  ↑    ↗      ↔   ↖↙←↙↓↖      
  ↗↔  ↕ ↑  →              ↙   
  ↘  ←↗ →↖ ↘  ↕  ←    ↖   ⤡   
  ↗         ←        ↙  ↑     
      ↙       ↖   ↓↖←     ↖ ↑ 
   ↓ ↓↑↙        → ↘↑↓↖        
   ↗ ↙←    ↑      ↙→     ↕    
  →                   ↖       
   ⤡    ↖       →↗ ↓     ↖    
    ↑            ↑ ↗↖
```

### How it works

It constructs the ASCII string "Hello, World!" bit by bit. A single bit at a time. Concatenated one after another. And then outputs the results.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6)

Short version:

```
[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]
.map(i => String.fromCharCode(i))
.reduce((i,j) => i+j)
```

Long version:

```
[1089,11089,22753,35749,48070,55639,56663,68984,80648,92312,102513,107697]
.reverse()
.map((i,j,k) => i-(++j==k.length ? 0 : k[j]))
.reverse()
.map(i => Math.sqrt(i))
.reverse()
.map(i => String.fromCharCode(i))
.reduce((i,j) => i+j)
```

---

If anyone is interested, the array is obtained using

```
"Hello World!"
.split('')
.map(i => String.charCodeAt(i,0))
.reverse()
.map(i => i*i)
.map((i,j,k) => k.slice(0,j+1)
.reduce((i,j) => i+j,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java (no literals except the zero :)

```java
class A{static char a=0,b=a++,e=a++,f=(char)(a/a);static char p(String s){return(char)Byte.parseByte(s,a);}public static void main(String[]z){long x=e,y=b;String c=((Long)x).toString(),d=((Long)y).toString();char l=p(c+c+d+c+c+d+d),m=p(c+c+d+d+c+d+c),o=(char)(l+a+f);b=p(c+d+d+d+d+d);e=b++;System.out.print(new char[]{p(c+d+d+c+d+d+d),m,l,l,o,e,p(c+d+c+d+c+c+c),o,(char)(o+a+f),l,(char)(m-f),b});}}
```

partly deobfuscated and commented version to explain

```java
class A
{

    //initializing some constants needed
    static char a = 0, b = a++, e = a++, f = (char) (a / a);



    //shorthand for parseByte() (codegolfing handyness)
    static char p(String s)
    {
        return (char) Byte.parseByte(s, a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] z)
    {
        long x = e, y = b; //needed for some weird reason to save bytes
        String c = ((Long) x).toString(), d = ((Long) y).toString(); //creating a 1 and a 0 a string
        char l = p(c + c + d + c + c + d + d),  //binary digit vodoo
        m = p(c + c + d + d + c + d + c),  //more commonly used letters prepared
        o = (char) (l + a + f);   
        b = p(c + d + d + d + d + d);
        e = b++;
        System.out.print(new char[]  //assembling the string with arithmetic and more binary stuff
        {
            p(c + d + d + c + d + d + d)
            ,
            m, l, l, o, e, 
            p(c + d + c + d + c + c + c), 
            o, (char) (o + a + f),
            l, 
            (char) (m - f), b
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two varients, both python, I posted for different questions:

1:

```
print str().join([chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~(0)))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))+~0*~0),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0)**(~0*(~0+~0+~0)))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0)**(~0*(~0+~0+~0)))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0))*~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0+~0+~0)+~0),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))+~0),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0))*~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0+~0+~0)+~0),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))+(~0*(~0+~0))**((~0+~0)*(~0+~0))+~0+~0),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0)**(~0*(~0+~0+~0)))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))*(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0))),
                  chr((~0*(~0+~0))**(~0*(~0+~0+~0+~0+~0))+~0*~0)
                  ])
```

2:

```
from string import lowercase
from string import uppercase
from string import punctuation
print uppercase[len(str([[[len(str())]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[]]]]]]]))]
print punctuation[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print
print uppercase[len(str([[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[[len(str())]]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([len(str())]))]
print punctuation[len(str())]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C99

Since almost all Hello World-implementations are one-liners, I made it a one-liner, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", (__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*((__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])), (__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*(__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), (__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*((__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])), (__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*((__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])), __func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]+(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), (((__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]))*(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]))>>(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), (__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])+(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])/(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*(__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])*(__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]), __func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]+(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), __func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]+(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]), __func__[0]-(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), __func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])]+(__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])-(__func__[3]-__func__[0]), ((__func__[0]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])-(__func__[3]-__func__[0]))*((__func__[3]-__func__[(__func__[3]-__func__[0])+(__func__[3]-__func__[0])])-(__func__[3]-__func__[0])-(__func__[3]-__func__[0])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AniRad](https://github.com/Adriandmen/AniRad/)

The 2D esolang which looks like a magic square.

```
 # # #   # # # #
#5+7*3      *2  =C
 / * +       *
#9*9+9+5+6      =C
   + *   +
#> 9*9+1+9  +9+8=C
   +     +   * *
#^ 9     > 4*6  =C
     +     *
#9+1*9+9+5+3  +4=C
   + -     * - +
#  6-6  +4*9+8 1=C
   = =     = = =
   C C     C C C
```

Programing this is quite a puzzle, it's like solving a magic square, because the output needs to be equal to the ASCII code. The harder part of programming is when the paths overlap each other.

All the paths executed:

```
(1)  5+7*3*2           = (((5+7)*3)*2)            = 72  = H
(2)  9*9+9+5+6         = ((((9*9)+9)+5)+6)        = 101 = e
(3)  9*9+1+9+9+8       = (((((9*9)+1)+9)+9)+8)    = 108 = l
(4)  9*9+1+9+9+8       = (((((9*9)+1)+9)+9)+8)    = 108 = l
(5)  9+1*9+9+5+3+4     = (((((9+1)*9)+9)+5)+3)+4) = 111 = o
(6)  6-6+4*9+8         = ((((6-6)+4)*9)+8)        = 44  = ,
(7)  5/9*9+1+9+9+8     = ((((((5/9)*9)+1)+9)+9)+8)= 32  = 
(8)  7*9+9+9+6         = ((((7*9)+9)+9)+6)        = 87  = W
(9)  3+9*9+9-6         = ((((3+9)*9)+9)-6)        = 111 = o
(10) 6+9+4*6           = (((6+9)+4)*6)            = 114 = r
(11) 4*3*9             = ((4*3)*9)                = 108 = l
(12) 2*9*6-8           = (((2*9)*6)-8)            = 100 = d
(13) 8*4+1             = (8*4)+1                  = 33  = !
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ObfuscatedHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] y = new int[,]  {{p(), p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), p(), p(), p(), p(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), n(), p(), }, 
                                    {p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), n(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), p(), p(), p(), p(), n(), p(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), n(), p(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), p(), n(), n(), p(), p(), p(), n(), }, 
                                    {p(), n(), n(), n(), p(), n(), p(), p(), }, };
            for (int i = 0; i < s(gr().ToArray()[21], 1) / gr().ToArray()[1]; i++)
            {
                bool[] h = new bool[8];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    h[j] = pr(y[i,j]);
                }
                cw(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{o(b(h), b())}));
            }
        }
        static void cw(string st)
        {
            using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
            {
                foreach (char c in st)
                    s.Write(c);
            }
        }
        static byte o(byte c, byte z)
        {
            int l = s((0xAA00 ^ 0x0), -8);
            l |= z;
            return (byte)(c ^ l);
        }
        static byte b()
        {
            return (byte)s(0xFF, s(4097,3));
        }
        static byte b(bool[] a)
        {
            byte v = 0;
            foreach (bool b in a)
            {
                v = (byte)s(v, 1);
                if (b) v |= 1;
            }
            return v;
        }
        static int s(int i, int s)
        {
            if (s > 0)
            {
                i <<= s;
                return i;
            }
            i >>= s + (s << 1);
            return i;
        }
        static string pa(string st)
        {
            for (int il = 0; il < s(gr().ToArray()[11], 1) - st.Length; il++)
                st = "0" + st;
            return st;
        }
        static IEnumerable<byte> gr()
        {
            byte[] m = Convert.FromBase64String("AwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZg==");
            foreach (byte bh in m)
                yield return o(o(bh, b()), b());
        }
        static byte eb(bool[] ar)
        {
            byte v = 0;
            foreach (bool b in ar)
            {
                v <<= gr().ToArray()[1] - 3;
                if (b) v |= (byte)(gr().ToArray()[8] - gr().ToArray()[7]);
            }
            return v;
        }
        static int p()
        {
            foreach(byte b in gr())
                if (pr(b))
                    return b;
            return gr().ToArray()[gr().ToArray()[8] - gr().ToArray()[6]];
        }
        static int n()
        {
            foreach (byte b in gr())
                if (!pr(b))
                    return b;
            return gr().ToArray()[gr().ToArray()[0]];
        }
        static bool f(bool g)
        {
            return ((l(g) << gr().ToArray()[0] - 2) % gr().ToArray()[3] - 3 == 0);
        }
        static int l(bool k)
        {
            return (k ? (gr().ToArray()[12] >> gr().ToArray()[1]) : 0);
        }
        static bool pr(int t)
        {
            for (int i = gr().ToArray()[0] - 1; i < t; i++)
                if (t % i == 0)
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## tinyBF

(I used my converter from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48628/brainf-to-tinybf-converter/48634#48634), and now the code looks even worse than regular BF.)

```
>++++++++|=>=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=>+|>===>=>=+=>=+=>=+=+=>=|+|=+>=|=>=|+=>=+>>=+=+=+=+=>|>>|=>===+=+=+=+=+=+=+=====+=+=+===>=>=+=+=+=+=+=+=+==>>>=|=|+|>=|+|=>|>=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+===>=>===+=+=+==++++++==++++++++===>=>=+===>=+=+=+=+==
```

Enjoy figuring **that** one out.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy

I'm so bad at this.. if I at least could figure out how bloo used escaped Unicode :(

```
// Execute command on the shell 
def shell = new org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell() 
def completer = new org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.completion.KeywordSyntaxCompletor() 
def ensureClass = shell.class.name.substring(33).capitalize() 
def ensureSyntax = completer.class.name[0] 
execute(ensureClass + ensureSyntax + Character.toChars(20) + completer.class.name.substring(46,49).capitalize() + Character.toChars(108) + completer.class.name.substring(49,50) + Character.toChars(33), shell) 
    def execute (command, shell) { 
    println command 
    shell.execute(command)     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure what the rules of strings are for ><>...
so I just won't use `"` or `'`. Fun.

I haven't tested it yet (my computer's a 2006 HP something-or-other laptop) and I had to press "wait" (instead of "kill page") on my browser at least 10 times, so I gave up.

I used [this](http://fishlanguage.com) for interpreting.

Okay, okay, here's the code.

```
05aaa***&01.
 021&:&?!.~~&1-&01.
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++o;
```

Good luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam

```
'p'z-iY#)c:R5'Bi+)(c):K\Ri-7-c_K'zi83-+c'!(c44Z1-*(c'<i2*9-c'2i2*c12Y#30-c'5i2*))c@'")((
```

[Try It](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='p'z-iY%23)c%3AR5'Bi%2B)(c)%3AK%5CRi-7-c_K'zi83-%2Bc'!(c44Z1-*(c'%3Ci2*9-c'2i2*c12Y%2330-c'5i2*))c%40'%22)(()

I'll add an explanation later.

Comment: When is 'later'? This answer was posted in July 2015.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

```
v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71=[ function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return 'c2fc6ebf83d192af1de8fb65d5778ca5fc90592eefc92760fdfd7b8cf79cf189162f99ef';}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return v5d5475885a1202b0caa18c691be08fbb.createElement(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1);}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1[0].getContext(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1[1]);}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1[0].text=va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1[1];}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return null;}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){'14019988a92023b21c8fbafb2b615c6ce575da38d2e924df6ff4aba407d2efc7e3b4e41b';}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){return 'c0ba17c23a26ff8c314478bc69f30963a6e4a7540ca1f991bf30dd786c7d46f3c4c6bd7e';}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1.style.display='none';return va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1;}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8.onload=va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1}, function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8.src=va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1;}, new Function("va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1","return unescape(decodeURIComponent(window.atob(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1)))"), function(va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1){v5ff03722a41320c4f93431969381ec49=new Function('va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1',v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[10](v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1]));return v5ff03722a41320c4f93431969381ec49;}]; v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e=[0,255,1]; v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e=[ 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2NhbnZhcyclM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ25vbmUnJTNC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJzJkJyUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ3NjcmlwdCclM0I=', '', 'vbfac34ee0630f6ced1b27977412b8d57', 'v4526e93cb60f112bfca2fcacd3d5ad5d', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2RhdGElM0FpbWFnZSUyRnBuZyUzQmJhc2U2NCUyQyclM0I=', '', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAGCAIAAABvrngfAAAAWklEQVQImQXBoRKCQABF0eubtWCyWUlGhs/Zz2YI2B2TgeAOULx6zqnWqtCbFna9JB5ykyn85JxoyTU+zCjCrF8KIQO8Y2cG+KTwwjXZ5B4mOSw20vSZLEDAP6drLptjIa2RAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwdjVkNTQ3NTg4NWExMjAyYjBjYWExOGM2OTFiZTA4ZmJiLmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKHZhNzNkOWNmZjQyYWNkNjUyNDQ4NTkxMjExZjM0MDBiMSklM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwZG9jdW1lbnQ=', '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', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwbmV3JTIwSW1hZ2UoKSUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwU3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29kZSh2YTczZDljZmY0MmFjZDY1MjQ0ODU5MTIxMWYzNDAwYjEpJTNC']; v5d5475885a1202b0caa18c691be08fbb=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](11)(); vbe04812f7fb403c83131d063b654a5c3=new Function('va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1',v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[10](v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[10])); vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[7](v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](13)()); v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[8](function(){ vdda97ed196cb536f1496aa6a81b33d72=vbe04812f7fb403c83131d063b654a5c3(v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[5]); v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[1](v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](0)()); v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df.width=vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8.width; v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df.height=vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8.height; v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df.style.display=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](1)();vb6ed2b2684bfe2ed677e1135c6ee8372=v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[4]; v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[2]([v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df,v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](2)()]); v3f7339ff7855d2aeef45ac5491776527=new Function('va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1',v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[10](v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[14])); v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec.drawImage(vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8, v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e[0], v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e[0]); v96b15a8c60e1861c85dd73c63b7a71ce=v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec.getImageData(v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e[0], v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e[0],v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df.width,v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df.height); v5dffb0184226196f2cf7435b845bfda4=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](12)(); (new Function(v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[10](vb6ed2b2684bfe2ed677e1135c6ee8372)))(); vbfac34ee0630f6ced1b27977412b8d57=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);vbf5d1804090f63bcb107d2a87b57b9b8=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](vbfac34ee0630f6ced1b27977412b8d57);v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v5ab9565a452a9f50031efed8ddd013df);v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v96b15a8c60e1861c85dd73c63b7a71ce);v96b15a8c60e1861c85dd73c63b7a71ce=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);vd99f3eaa3da59d0ad5bc3c714ddc3886=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);vb6ed2b2684bfe2ed677e1135c6ee8372=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v7016a415496ec94a5cabace1b5537dff=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v30bb84c48868dbc2a98b1d81b474d5ed=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);vbfac34ee0630f6ced1b27977412b8d57=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v46bfbf7aad13509a20fd3fa12522db63=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v5d5475885a1202b0caa18c691be08fbb=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v5dffb0184226196f2cf7435b845bfda4=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);v96a951a6897b594539298e713dee6d5e=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec);va73d9cff42acd652448591211f3400b1=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](vdda97ed196cb536f1496aa6a81b33d72);v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[4](v0d219376b6991aa9e8d2d34cf5b08bec); }); v5dffb0184226196f2cf7435b845bfda4=v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[9](v65e4bebc4497f79a4d1b8673ad849e71[11](7)()+v21a3d2d3fc5c2c1e1f3a633bd8f16f7e[9]);
```

Probably the largest code with higher ratio of alphanumeric chars to other chars, too (7.1kB).

#### Explanation

Basically `alert('Hello, World!')` and put it [here](http://javascript2img.com/).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3

```
wizardry=42;twitter=4
STRlNG=20;r=22;STR0NG=5
for STRING in range(0,200):
    if STRING == 3 or 42 or 69:wizardy+=7
unknown=wizardry+24.3333*3.0;amaze=STR0NG*20;r=STR0NG*20+2*5+1
lambdo=twitter*28-int(str(wizardry[1]))
calculus=lambdo;tt=30+3-1;evil=calculus*2-100-int(str(calculus[2]))
wut=STR0NG*2*10+1;game=r+STR0NG-2;c=calculus
def calcVelocity(lambdq):
    return(lambdq+10*3)
bmw=calcVelocity(2);magic=evil+c-evil
floatMagic=bmw+STR0NG+2*5-3
#--Everything is "normal" again--
helpMe=chr(wizardry);uhOh=chr(floatMagic);pleaseNo=chr(bmw)
agony=chr(amaze);evil42=chr(calculus);no=chr(unknown)
mario=chr(game);boo=chr(magic);fifty=chr(tt)
stone=chr(evil);rock=chr(r);umg=chr(wut)
print(helpMe,end='');print(no,end='');print(evil42,end='')
print(stone,end='');print(umg,end='');print(pleaseNo,end='')
print(uhOh,end='');print(rock,end='');print(mario,end='')
print(boo,end='');print(agony,end='');print(fifty,end='')
```

The beginning is weird. Really weird. (Unless you're a math nerd of course.) The end isn't too weird though. Any tips on obfuscating the end?

Comment: Does not compute.

Comment: second line should be `STRING` instead of `STRlNG` (small L!) ? And `STRONG` without the zero maybe?

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com)

Fairly simple. Stores ASCII values and in an array and prints their char value.

```
func main(){vals=[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100,33];foreach(val in vals)print(Convert.toChar(val));}
```

Run online and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=139165d5d49376f99097fcf020a6d9d9)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pushes the ASCII codes onto the stack, but since there is each character is considered an individual character in ><> the largest number you can write in one token is 15 (using f in hex) so to get larger values you must use a math operation eg. 32 = (8 x 4) = 84*. ><> is 2nd so it control flow in this one winds around in a spiral at the end it then goes on to a line that wraps around checking the length and outputting the stack until its empty. *Plus: hidden :) face!*

```
b3*aa*c9*v
v1*b8+1+<a
->a+1+cvaa
8*v*6 <9**
4a :) c*ae
*a >1+^:a+
>^ ^*aa<^<
  >l?!;o
```

[Try it here!](http://fishlanguage.com/playground)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell

Not really that weird. I feel like this is how many people see Haskell anyway.

```
main=let h#a=putChar.toEnum$h in 72#error>>(101:[])!!0#(\h e ll(o, w)0 r  l d '!'
->undefined)>>mapM_(#(#))(replicate 2 108++flip(:)[](foldl(\n d->10*n+d)
0.replicate 3$1))*>((\a b->a^b-a+b)7 2)#'o'>>= \_->(#error
['c','a','n',' ','y','o','u',' ','h','e','a','r',' ','m','e',',','w','o','r','l','d','?'])
(read((\x->show x++show(x-1))3)::Int)<*mapM_(#[q|q<-repeat '?'])((:)119$(:)111[114])>>= 
\x->((\x->2*(10*x!!0+x!!1))(take 2[5,4..]))#(\(hello,world)->'!')*>pure id<*>((#
(\[hello,world]->(!!)))$(^2)([1..10]!!9))>>(read.concat$show<$>(take 2(repeat((\(x:xs)->x)
(drop 2[1..])))))# \[puts,(hello, world)]->error
```

It works by taking the ASCII codes for the characters in "Hello world!", converting them to characters and printing them one by one. None of the character literals, nor any parts which spell hello world are actually used in the program.

It's meant as a one-liner, but I tried to format it a little more nicely.