# Brainf*** to tinyBF converter

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck, conversion

*You don't need to know these languages to participate. All necessary information has been provided in this question.*

You should write a program or function which given a [brainfuck (BF)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) code as input outputs its [tinyBF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TinyBF) equivalent.

BF has 8 instructions characters: `+-><[],.` and tinyBF has 4: `=+>|`. Converting works the following way: starting from the beginning of the BF code each symbol is replaced by on of its two tinyBF counterparts based on the number of `=` signs in the tinyBF code until that point (i.e. `=` behaves like a toggle switch).

The converter table (with columns: Brainfuck symbol;  tinyBF symbol(s) when ther are even `=`'s before; tinyBF symbol(s) when ther are odd `=`'s before):

```
BF   even    odd

+      +      =+
-     =+       +
>      >      =>
<     =>       >
[      |      =|
]     =|       |
.     ==      ==
,    |=|    =|=|
```

(This creates an almost unique tinyBF code. The only conflict occurs if the BF code contains a `[]` which is generally unused as it creates an infinite void loop.)

### Input

- An at least 1 byte long valid brainfuck program containing only the characters `+-><[],.`
- Guaranteed not to contain the string `[]`
- Trailing newline is optional.

### Output

- A tinyBF program.
- Trailing newline is optional.

### Examples

You can convert any BF program to tinyBF with [this (1440 byte long) converter](http://bataais.com/tinyBF.html) (see the Edit section for a small deviation).

```
Format is Input into Output

++-  into  ++=+
,[.,]  into  |=||==|=|=| or |=|=|==|=|| (both is acceptable check the Edit section)
>++.--.[<]+-,  into  >++===++===|=>|=+=+=|=|
>++-+++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.  into  >++=+=+++++++|=>=+++++++++>=+|>==
```

### Edit

As @Jakube pointed out in the official tinyBF converter in the equivalents of the `,` BF instruction (`|=|` and `=|=|`) the last `=` signs aren't counted towards the toggle state. Both the official and mine interpretations are acceptable but you have to choose one.

This is code-golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: By 'odd' and 'even', do you mean the first character of the BF code is 'odd', the next is 'even', and so on?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I think what's meant is the number of `=` characters output before the character currently being translated. Think of the `=` character as a toggle between two instruction sets.

Comment: @orip OK, but what about things like `=|=| ` that don't change the even/odd value? Or is that part of the challenge?

Comment: Is input through a file, STDIN, or our choice?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Your choice.

Comment: I don't understand the second example: `,[.,]  into  |=||==|=|=|`. `,` transforms into `|=|`, then there is a odd number of `=`s, so why doesn't `[` transform into `=|`?

Comment: @Jakube You are correct. See the Edit section.

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that a dot as the very first character would be invalid because it makes no sense?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos No. It does make sense though as It outputs the character with codepoint 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CJam, 50 bytes

```
l{"..+-><[],"#2mdT2$@T?:T=L'=?"== + > | |=|"S/@=}/
```

Try [one example](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%7B%22..%2B-%3E%3C%5B%5D%2C%22%232mdT2%24%40T%3F%3AT%3DL'%3D%3F%22%3D%3D%20%2B%20%3E%20%7C%20%7C%3D%7C%22S%2F%40%3D%7D%2F&input=%3E%2B%2B.--.%5B%3C%5D%2B-%2C) or [all of them](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25%7B0%3AT%3B%7B%22..%2B-%3E%3C%5B%5D%2C%22%232mdT2%24%40T%3F%3AT%3DL'%3D%3F%22%3D%3D%20%2B%20%3E%20%7C%20%7C%3D%7C%22S%2F%40%3D%7D%2F%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=%2B%2B-%0A%2C%5B.%2C%5D%0A%3E%2B%2B.--.%5B%3C%5D%2B-%2C%0A%3E%2B%2B-%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%5B%3C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%3E-%5D%3C.) online.

#### Explanation

The magic is in the mapping! Looking up each operator's index in a carefully ordered yet simple string produces three useful pieces of information at once: whether the operator is directionless (index == 0), the direction the operator requires (index mod 2), and the index of the output operator (index / 2).

Using that handy mapping, it's a simple case of looping through each input operator and producing a direction swap operator if the direction needs to be changed, updating the direction, and producing the output operator.

```
l                   "Read a line of input.";
{                   "For each character of input:";
  "..+-><[],"#        "Map the character:
                        '.' -> 0  |
                        '+' -> 2  |  '-' -> 3
                        '>' -> 4  |  '<' -> 5
                        '[' -> 6  |  ']' -> 7
                        ',' -> 8  |            ";
  2md                 "Calculate the quotient and remainder of the mapping
                       divided by 2.";
  T2$@T?:T            "If the the mapping is nonzero (not '.'), set the
                       direction after this operator to the remainder above.
                       Otherwise ('.'), don't change the direction.";
  =L'=?               "If the direction before this operator is equal to the
                       direction after, produce an empty string. Otherwise,
                       produce the direction switch operator, '='.";
  "== + > | |=|"S/@=  "Map the previous mapping divided by 2 to an operator:
                         0 ('.')      -> '=='
                         1 ('+', '-') -> '+'
                         2 ('>', '<') -> '>'
                         3 ('[', ']') -> '|'
                         4 (',')      -> '|=|' ";
}/
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/) 276 bytes

(not counting uneccesary linefeeds)

```
{a<<]>&c}{b<<-]<[->}{c]<]>[>[}{d 4+[-<}3>4->3->5->-->>&d 4+>]<[-<
4+<3+<4+<8+4>]<[<]<<,[>3+&d 6->]+<-[-[-[-[14-[--[>&d 6->]+<+[--[[
-]>[-&c>.&b>>.<.<+&a->>.<.&b>.<&a->>.>>.3<&b 4>.4<&a 4>.3<&b+>>.>
>.6<]>]<]>[-3>..3<&c 3>.<<&b+>>.>.3<&a>>.<.>.<.&b+>.>.<.<&a->>.>.
<<&b 3>.5<]>]<,]
```

How to compile and run:

```
beef ebf.bf < tinybf.ebf > tinybf.bf
beef tinybf.bf < source.bf > source.tbf
```

It will work with any wrapping BF interpreter that uses/support 0 as EOF.
Actual EBF source before golfing:

```
:i:f:o:p:e:a:g
$p ~"|=+>"<[<]@o
$i,( $f+++++++(-$i------)+$i-; +
     ($i-; ,
       ($i-; -
         ($i-; .
           ($i--------------; <
             ($i--; >
               ($f++++(-$i------)+$i+; [
                 ($i--; ]
                   ((-) $f(-) )
                      $f ( $o[$p.$f-]<[@f-$e.$p.$o+$i] ) ; ]
                  ) $f ( $o[-$e.$p.$f-]<[@f-$p.$i] ) ; [
                ) $f ( $o[-$e.$g.$f-]<[@f-$g.$i] ) ; >
              ) $f ( $o[$g.$f-]<[@f-$o+$e.$g.$i] ) ; <
            ) $f (- $e.. ) ; .
          ) $f ( $o[$a.$f-]<[@f-$o+$e.$a.$i] ) ; -
        ) $f ( $o[$e.$p.$e.$p.$f-]<[@f-$o+$p.$e.$p.$i] ) ; ,
     ) $f ( $o[-$e.$a.$f-]<[@f-$a.$i] ) ; +
$i,)
```

## BrainFuck 404 bytes

This is the trimmed output of the compiled EBF.

```
>>>---->--->----->-->>++++[-<++++>]<[-<++++<+++<++++<++++++++>>>>]<
[<]<<,[>+++++++[-<------>]+<-[-[-[-[--------------[--[>++++[-<-----
->]+<+[--[[-]>[-]<]>[>[>.<<-]<[->>>.<.<+<<]>]<]>[>[->>.<.<<-]<[->>.
<<<]>]<]>[>[->>.>>.<<<<<-]<[->>>>>.<<<<<<]>]<]>[>[>>>>.<<<<<-]<[->+
>>.>>.<<<<<<]>]<]>[->>>..<<<]<]>[>[>>>.<<<<-]<[->+>>.>.<<<<<]>]<]>[
>[>>.<.>.<.<<-]<[->+>.>.<.<<<]>]<]>[>[->>.>.<<<<-]<[->>>>.<<<<<]>]<,]
```

Comment: So it's converting BF to TinyBF... in BF. That's AWESOME.

Answer (score 2):

## TinyBF***, 558 bytes

Don't credit me for this, this is the TinyBF version of @Sylwester's BrainF*** answer (I used his code to convert his code into this code, :P). I just felt the need to put this answer up.

```
>>>=++++=>=+++=>=+++++=>=++=>>++++|=+>=++++>=|>=|=+>=++++=>=+++=>=++++=>=+++++++
+>>>>=|>=|=>|>>=|=|=|>+++++++|=+>++++++=>=|=+=>+=|=+=|=+=|=+=|=++++++++++++++=|=
++=|>++++|=+>++++++=>=|=+=>=+|=++=||=+|=>|=+|>|=>|>|>===>>+|>=|=+=>>>===>==>=+=>
>|=>=|>|=>|>|=+=>>===>==>>+|>=|=+=>>===>>>|=>=|>|=>|>|=+=>>==>>===>>>>>+|>=|=+=>
>>>>===>>>>>>|=>=|>|=>|>|>>>>===>>>>>+|>=|=+=>+>>==>>===>>>>>>|=>=|>|=>|=+=>>>==
===>>>|>|=>|>|>>>===>>>>+|>=|=+=>+>>==>===>>>>>|=>=|>|=>|>|>>===>===>===>==>>+|>
=|=+=>+>==>===>==>>>|=>=|>|=>|>|=+=>>==>===>>>>+|>=|=+=>>>>===>>>>>|=>=|>=|=||
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>244</s> <s>241</s> <s>226</s> 217 bytes

```
open(B,$ARGV[0]);%e=qw(+ + - =+ > > < => [ | ] =| . == , |=|);%o=qw(+ =+ - + > => < > [ =| ] | . == , =|=|);$q=0;while(<B>){$p='';@c=split('');foreach$c(@c){if($q%2>0){$p.=$o{$c}}else{$p.=$e{$c};}$q=$p=~/=/g;}print$p}
```

Works on all cases. Run with `perl file.pl [filename]` where `file.pl` is the name of the program, and `[filename]` is the name of the BF file.
**Changes**

- Saved 3 bytes by using `split('')` instead of `split('',$_)`.
- Saved 15 bytes by:

  - Getting rid of `$f=` in front of open (3 bytes)
  - Replacing `if($eo%2==1)` with `if($eo%2>0)` (1 byte)
  - Replacing `$p=$p.` with `$p.=` (2 bytes * 2 times = 4 bytes)
  - Removing trailing newline, as it was optional (5 bytes)
  - Removed `=()` (3 bytes)
- Saved 9 bytes by shortening variable names.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 91 bytes

```
o:0;{:[i:"..+-><[],"?x;t:i!2;t:0];`0::[o=t;"";"="],("==";"+";">";"|";"|=|")@i%2;o::t}',/0:`
```

It's more-or-less a direct port of @Runer112's CJam answer. And it's much longer. Life sucks.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 129 bytes

```
b=>[...b].map(x=>p+="=+,+,=>,>,=|,|,==,=|=|,+,=+,>,=>,|,=|,==,|=|".split`,`["+-><[].,".indexOf(x)+p.split`=`.length%2*8],p="")&&p
```

Uses an array of the 16 possibilities (8 characters times 2 parities), and indexes into this. The array is built by splitting a string, which saves 26 bytes over an array.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>233</s> 217 bytes

```
p,m,g,l,b,s,d,a,q,f=%w(+ - > < [ ] . , | =)
z=[{p=>p,m=>f+p,g=>g,l=>f+g,b=>q,s=>f+q,d=>f+f,a=>q+f+q},{p=>f+p,m=>p,g=>f+g,l=>g,b=>f+q,s=>q,d=>f+f,a=>f+q+f+q}]
i=0
ARGV[0].each_char{|c|v=z[i%2][c];print v;i+=v.count(f)}
```

An 8-byte improvement on the previous non-esoteric answers!
Saved 16 bytes with the [`%w()` syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 101 bytes

```ruby
->s{t="";s.chars{|c|t<<((t.count(?=)+i="..+-><[],".index(c))%2<1&&i>0?"":?=)+%w(= + > | |=|)[i/2]};t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7BasMwDL3vK4RHi4Nib@txtdzTvsL4kLguMRtJiR22UffbsySlW9h7ICQ96Un9UH@PJxqFjpdEjO2jdE3Vx0t2OSnFeZKuG9rED1RgICYlCq2MLZkM7dF/cVcUm5162W6Dfj4w9jrPbT45AYKGDJlyYcLTzl736TqehxThZBiiYPYRILSpA0AkfLhLpZGlXYmTQSbKM6HrYUmWOgOvu9RAiFA558@pqj88uMa7d0iNh7djSBC9S6Fri197jSiFkEZZFOXqzNQnoiVk0pmml@Yj6z2BNxiFd2hhlfznMvGGyYf@JgmzJhp/AA)

Uses the second interpretation of the ambiguous `,` translation rule.